# Upgrading my motherboard completely

Tags: windows-7, cpu, motherboard, upgrade

I have a terrible motherboard:

**Manufacturer**: Foxconn
**Model**: 2AB1
**Chipset**: AMD 785G
**Southbridge**: AMD SB700
**Brand**: American MegaTrends INC.

It wont let me overclock my CPU, so I've decided to upgrade it. I am going to get a motherboard with a socket AM3 and DDR3 RAM for my supplies that will let me overclock. Want I want to know is:

1. When I upgrade my motherboard, do I need to reinstall anything?
2. Will I still have Windows 7 Premium?
3. Will I need new drivers or anything such?

Comment: Sigh, I again see a question(like this one) get so many(at least 3) gratuitous down votes, just because some novice people thinks it is ridiculous, stupid or unanswerable, BUT actually there is an elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first question is the most critical one. In the most common case, changing your motherboard(but not your hard disk) will result in 0x7B(INACCESSABLE_BOOT_DEVICE) blue screen on booting. Microsoft does not seem to provide an official way to help you out. However, there are commercial software solutions available. One choice is to use [Paragon Hard disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-professional/)'s boot disk, execute **P2P adjust OS**, then you will be able to boot your original Windows with your new mobo. Basically, **P2P adjust OS** adjust your Windows registry offline so that Windows' next boot uses the new correct "boot device" on your new hardware platform. Another choice may be Acronis Universal Restore, roughly the same concept as **P2P adjust OS**. This way, you don't need to install anything, almost.

For question 2, sure, you have the same Windows 7, except that you probably need to re-activate it due to hardware change.

For question 3, you can install any driver you like after login into your Windows desktop after mobo upgrade.

Comment: You can do the boot device adjustment with startup repair (and/or manual BCD editing commands) from a Windows recovery/installation DVD, if you want.

Comment: I do not understand your answer concerning 'most common case'. I switched a few times my mother board and never ever had any problems with the os on my hard disk. (except for re-activation of course). I think that in most cases there won't be any problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

1. I switched motherboards a few times and I also switched hard disks with an OS installed on it to other computers and never had any real problems.
   As Jimm Chen mentioned in his answer, it is possible to get the `Stop Code 0x7B`. However, this will only occur if you [switch the type of chipset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316401), like switching from AMD to Intel.
   However, as you mentioned yourself, the chipset stays the same (AM3). I do not expect any problems there. If there are problems, look at the [answer](https://superuser.com/a/739208/106036) of Jimm Chen.
2. The OS of your system has nothing to do with your motherboard. So, yes.
3. You switched hardware, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Sure, I try to address the most critical cases. And I think most people changing motherboard because it has been too old(years ago) or damaged, and, they wish to upgrade to the current mainstream board(if they knew the correct way) instead of staying with the same-generation years-old motherboard.

Comment: The information in http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316401 is outdated and misleading, no kidding! He told you in method 1 to do an in-place upgrade of XP. But how dare you do that with your original XP installation CD in case you have installed so many software/patches on your live system. You're risking losing Windows/3rd-party-software function/configuration lost if you dare to try.

Comment: The link was meant as a source why the error could happen the same counts still for Windows 7. I agree it is out dated in the perspective of the solution.